# calculate Third monday of every three month in java?

Tags: java, date

```
LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(2015, 3, 22);           
LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate(2015, 9, 30);           
PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withYearsRemoved();

Period difference = new Period(date1, date2, monthDay);             
int months = difference.getMonths();            
int days = difference.getDays();                
int alertMonth = 2;             
int intervalLoop = date2.getMonthOfYear() / alertMonth ;            
for(int i=date1.getMonthOfYear();i<date2.getMonthOfYear();i++){             
         int intervalTime = i * alertMonth;             
         if(intervalTime >13){

               return;          
         }else{
  LocalDate d = getNDayOfMonth( DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY, 2, i, 2015);
  System.out.println("month----> "+i+" "+d);
```

Comment: so, what did you try so far? what's not working here?

Comment: please any one provide code.

Comment: You should indicate the library you are using (i.e joda time in this case). Also this is not how SO works.

Comment: code for what? you paste just a mess into a question. don't expect that you will have answer, until you fix question

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: "*please any one provide code*"  What do you call what you posted?

Comment: Bit of effort required...

Comment: Are you using joda time or java 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How do I get the date of x day in a month ( e.g. Third Monday in February 2012)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946129/java-how-do-i-get-the-date-of-x-day-in-a-month-e-g-third-monday-in-february)

Comment: s, i am using joda library in abow code, i want java code for calculate like third monday of every 2 months or 3 months, please any one have provide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This code may help..***

```
DateTime urDate = DateTime(date);                               //Your Date time
DateTime afterThreeMonths = urDate.plusMonths(6);               //Add 3 months to your Date
afterThreeMonths.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);       //Find next monday  
afterThreeMonths.plusWeeks(2);                                  //Add two more weeks to the first monday.
```

NB: *I never run this code. Try and find it out urself.*