# Java 8 Date API - Get ordinal position of the day in the month

Tags: java, java-8, date

Inspired by the following posts

- [Get the first Monday of a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971439/get-the-first-monday-of-a-month)
- [Java: How do I get the date of x day in a month ( e.g. Third Monday in February 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946129/java-how-do-i-get-the-date-of-x-day-in-a-month-e-g-third-monday-in-february)

I need a function that returns the ordinal position for a given day in the month, for example:

> 01/01/1970 = **1** *because it's the **first** Thursday in January, 1970*
>
> 02/01/1970 = **1** *because it's the **first** Friday in January, 1970*
>
> 19/01/1970 = **3** *because it's the **third** Monday in January, 1970*
>
> 31/01/1970 = **5** *because it's the **fifth** Saturday in January, 1970*

What have I tried? - Nothing...I don't even know where to start; the Java 8 date/time API is pretty new to me.

Ideally I want a function with this signature:

```
public int getOrdinalPosition(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So the cardinal position refers to the week number in the month where the given date falls?

Comment: Actually, asking for the “nth” is *ordinal* not *cardinal*. Ordinal means counting by position. Cardinal means counting for quantity. See: https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-cardinal-numbers-and-vs-ordinal-numbers/

Comment: @BasilBourque good point well made, thanks for your update!

Answer (score 4):

Well, take 19/01/1970. Subtract 7 days from that and it's.. still january. Subtract 7 days again and.. still january. Subtract 7 days a 4th time and.. oh hey it's no longer january. The 4th time you removed 7 days, it ceased to be the right month.

That's all you need here.

Relevant methods: a for loop, a counter, and.. the `minusDays(7)` method, and `getMonth()`.

Answer (score 3):

## `ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH`

You can use `LocalDate.get()` and `ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaApplication19 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.of(1970, 01, 01);
        LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.of(1970, 02, 01);
        LocalDate localDate3 = LocalDate.of(1970, 01, 19);
        LocalDate localDate4 = LocalDate.of(1970, 01, 31);


        System.out.println(localDate1.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println(localDate2.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println(localDate3.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println(localDate4.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH));

        System.out.println(getOrdinalPosition(localDate4));
    }

    static public int getOrdinalPosition(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        return LocalDate.from(temporal).get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
run:
1
1
3
5
5
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: By the way, should be `getOrdinalPosition` (not cardinal).

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't know the difference. I just looked it up. You appear to be correct. I just copied the OPs template.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work...

```
public int getOrdinalPosition(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    return ((LocalDate.from(temporal).getDayOfMonth() - 1) / 7) + 1;
}
```

Comment: @RavindraRanwala readability is in the eye of the beholder; short code tends to put the burden of proof on the longer code, and you didn't bring any. This is not error prone whatsoever; it does precisely what OP wanted (which is NOT 'the number of the week the day is in', it is 'this is the Xth thursday of the month; what's X?'

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)

```
LocalDate.of(1970,1,1).get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)      //1
LocalDate.of(1970,1,2).get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)      //1
LocalDate.of(1970,1,19).get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)     //3
LocalDate.of(1970,1,31).get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)     //5
```